# Remove whitespace in plot in Matlab textstring where 'DefaultTextInterpreter' is 'Latex'

Tags: spacing, matlab

With MWE:

```
set(0,'DefaultTextInterpreter','Latex');
x = linspace(0,10,1e2);
fx = sin(x);

Xpos = 0.1;
Ypos = 0.83;
plot(x,fx);
hTag = text(Xpos,Ypos,'(a)'); set(hTag,'FontSize',23);
```

I get (too much) whitespace between the character 'a' and the brackets. How do I remove it?

Comment: What's the generated LaTeX code?

Comment: I don't see what you mean – the MWE gives an amount of whitespace which is too excessive. Can it somehow be reduced?

Comment: That code is by no means related to LaTeX, apart from a string.

Comment: I thought that maybe it was the LaTeX interpreter that made the trouble.

Comment: It might be, but surely LaTeX doesn't know what to do with that.

Comment: @egreg: the "LaTeX code" here is `(a)`, the argument to the text() function of Matlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple workaround: Don't use the 'latex' interpreter for this label, since it doesn't actually include any LaTeX commands. Of course, the font won't match other labels.

A more complicated workaround: Use [psfrag](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) which allows you to include LaTeX code within an eps file and then get it replaced by a rendered version upon inclusion in LaTeX. If you don't want to ultimately use the plot in LaTeX, there's also a way to export that psfrag-processed plot again as an eps.

You could also try and experiment with negative `\hspace` I guess.

Some background: Matlab does have a TeX+LaTeX installation included, which is actually underlying the 'Interpreter', 'latex' setting (but not the 'tex' setting!). There is a function `tex.m` in the graphics toolbox which receives LaTeX code and returns the generated dvi as binary data. Unfortunately, the dvi renderer included in Matlab is quite crappy and completely undocumented, so there's no chance of fixing it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435848/how-to-make-fonts-available-to-the-latex-interpreter-in-matlab-r2013a) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139497/dvi-with-explicit-positioning-of-each-character) for an impression of my own personal struggles with that. :-) As far as I can tell, if you want proper LaTeX-formatted text in Matlab plots, psfrag is the way to go.

Comment: negative \hspace worked beautifully.